# Error adding Data Source in Lucee v5

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, lucee

I have a fresh install of Lucee 5.2.8.50 running on Windows Server 2016 along with a fresh install of MYSql 8.0.12 with Legacy Authentication enabled.

I did a data dump of a production database I have and imported it in my new MYSql install without issue. When I try to create a datasource mapping in the Lucee administrator page, I get the following error:

```
Cannot open file:C:\Tomcat\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\lucee-server\context\security\cacerts [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Update:
I’ve also reconfigured my MySQL installation and set authentication type to legacy. Same error. I’ve also noticed that if I view the user’s property I can see the authentication type is set to caching_sha2_password and I’m unable to change it. Screenshot is attached.

[image]

Comment: https://dev.lucee.org/t/cannot-open-file-opt-lucee-tomcat-lucee-server-context-security-cacerts-keystore-was-tampered-with-or-password-was-incorrect/3766

Comment: This link doesn't help me.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why not? What did you try and what was the result?

Comment: Yes sorry, according to the link you can add the datasource without choosing to verify it and it will add, which I tried and it did add it on my end. But I still receive that same error when running CFM code against the datasource. I also added the following code to my lucee-server.xml file and still no success: &amp;useSSL=false&amp;requireSSL=false . Error message: Cannot open file:C:\Tomcat\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\lucee-server\context\security\cacerts [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect]

Comment: From https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/caching-sha2-pluggable-authentication.html >> `To connect to the server using an account that authenticates with the caching_sha2_password plugin, you must use either a secure connection or an unencrypted connection that supports password exchange using an RSA key pair, as described later in this section. Either way, the caching_sha2_password plugin uses MySQL's encryption capabilities. See Section 6.4, “Using Encrypted Connections”.` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encrypted-connections.html

Comment: Browsing through those links may point you in the right direction.